# Can I replace a valve's round knob with a lever?

Tags: plumbing

I have a water shutoff valve with a round handle. I am installing an automatic shutoff system but it requires a straight handle. Can I replace just the round valve handle with a straight lever?

Comment: Seems like your needing a ball valve (1/4 turn to off) rather than a standard gate valve?

Answer (score 1):

Probably. It's hard to say with the almost nothing you've told us about the valve.

You could also mount a bar right to the round knob if that suits your shutoff mechanism. It could be spaced off a bit to present the exact size and shape expected by the device.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, which is limited as I am not a plumber, **probably not**.

A shutoff valve with a lever is normally 1/4 turn. A shutoff valve with a knob is typically one or more FULL turns. Attaching a lever will make it easier to turn manually, but won't work for an automated mechanism which is typically designed for 1/4 turn or at most 1/2 turn.

You may also want to consider an electrically controlled valve rather than a separate device that turns the valve. Something like [this](https://www.smarthome.com/smarthome-select-electronic-water-shutoff-valve-3-4-inch-12v-dc.html):

[image]

This would be in addition to your existing valve, as you don't want the only shutoff to require electricity (and that may not be permitted by code anyway).